# How to run a multi-route angular app in a single page

Tags: angularjs

Imagine we have an AngularJs app (witten in multiple controllers, services, directive and run method) for multiple routes using `$routeProvider`. and now we need to use the same application in a single page. meaning that templates of different routes should now be visible in one page at the same time.

I can't use different `iframes` because then it's hard to access the `$scope`s of those `controllers` from the wrapper application.
Is this possible without the use of `iframe`s?

Comment: Use directives?

Comment: @Ankh How? Can you please explain more?

Comment: Do not seem any success this way.

Comment: @Ankh Is it possible to bootstrap an application through a certain path or for a certain controller?

Comment: `templates of different routes should now be visible in one page` wrap your pages into directives then you can include them wherever you want. `<page-one></page-one><page-two></page-two>`

Comment: iframes should **never** be considered in an angular app.  beyond that, there are multiple ways to have child routes, depending on your app structure, and you aren't showing enough here to do anything more than make guesses at what you might need.

Comment: @Claies Thank you for commenting. About the `iframe`s I agree with you, that's why I'm asking for another approach. About child routes, as I mentioned in the question, my problem is not routing, is about how to show all the routes of a single instance of application simultaneously in one page. but the problem is not about details, it's just about how to bootstrap a standard app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController). Using ng-include, You can insert a html into the block containing it and using ng-controller, you can insert a controller for the same block. I would prefer not to use iframes as it is a bad practice and you will not be able to access scope and a lot of features that are native to angular.

EDIT : Since, you are using the run() function you can try the below approach :

Keeping the routeProvider same, you can move the contents of you html template files into script tags on you index.html like so :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="one.tpl.html">
 //Your html template code goes here
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="two.tpl.html">
 //Your html template code goes here
</script>
```

In you app.js :

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'one.tpl.html', //points to the content of the script tag in your index.html file
        controller: 'onetplCtrl'
      }).
      when('/edit',{
        templateUrl:'two.tpl.html', //points to the content of the script tag in your index.html file
        controller:'twotplCtrl'
      }).
       otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
```

Comment: This was my first idea, The problem is I'm using `run()` method in my app which plays a crucial role in the application. and I can't find a solution to get it work with this approach.

Comment: Then you can use ng-template to load a particular template to $templateCache which can be used like a normal reference to html file and along with ngRoute pointing a controller to this template, it will work the same as declaring everythng in the routeProvider

Comment: I tried your approach and in fact, when I bootstrap the app using `ng-app` on any element, the `run()` method is called and if I use `ng-controller` and `ng-include` on different elements inside that, everything works fine. they all have access to`$rootScope`. Thank you